# Converting postman snipet to python JSON

Tags: python, json, postman

```
payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"C:\\Users\\Muvi\\Downloads\\poster3.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pinataMetadata \"\r\n\r\n{\n    name: 'muvidocument.pdf'\n    keyvalues: {\n        LawyerName: 'Lawyer001',\n        ClientID: 'Client002',\n        ChargeCode: 'Charge003'\n        Cost: 100.00\n    }\n}\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
```

I am trying to write postman snipet to python JSON, but I am having trouble writing it properly.
So far I have been able to write the above in JSON format. But I dont think it is the correct representation. When I use the above payload data then api request becomes success but when I use the below one it gives me error.

```
payload = {
    "file":{"filename":r"C:\Users\Muvi\Downloads\poster3.jpg\"},
    "pinataMetadata":{
                "name": 'muvidocument.pdf',
                "keyvalues":{
                    "LawyerName": "Lawyer001",
                    "ClientID": "Client002",
                    "ChargeCode": "Charge003",
                    "Cost": 100.00
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the incorrectly escaped `"` in the filename, why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: The name value (`'muvidocument.pdf'`) needs to be wrapped in double quotes like other string fields

Comment: @Sachin still does not work

Comment: Can you share what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @Sachin I am hitting a thrid party api, when i  use postman snippet payload it gives me response 200 but when i  use my json it gives me 400 error..

Comment: Your json is not valid. Test it at https://jsonlint.com. If you still have problems after you're sure you have valid json, update the question.

Comment: BTW, When I tried to validate your json, it forced me to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"file": {
    "filename": "C:\\Users\\Muvi\\Downloads\\poster3.jpg"
},
"pinataMetadata": {
    "name": "muvidocument.pdf",
    "keyvalues": {
        "LawyerName": "Lawyer001",
        "ClientID": "Client002",
        "ChargeCode": "Charge003",
        "Cost": 100.0
    }
}
```

}